# Definable collections without definable members (in ZF)

Tags: set-theory

Denote Zermelo Fraenkel set theory without choice by ZF. Is the following true: In ZF, every definable non empty class A has a definable member; i.e. for every class $A = \lbrace x : \phi(x)\rbrace$ for which ZF proves "A is non empty", there is a class $a = \lbrace x : \psi(x)\rbrace$ such that ZF proves "a belongs to A"?

Comment: Writing "id est" is really really pedantic.

Comment: @HarryGindi: Why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update.** (June, 2017) François Dorais and I have completed a paper that ultimately grew out of this questions and several follow-up questions.

> F. G. Dorais and J. D. Hamkins, [When does every definable nonempty set have a definable element?](http://jdh.hamkins.org/when-does-every-definable-nonempty-set-have-a-definable-element/) ([arχiv:1706.07285](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07285))
>
> > ***Abstract.** The assertion that every definable set has a definable element is equivalent over ZF to the principle $V=\newcommand\HOD{\text{HOD}}\HOD$, and indeed, we prove, so is the assertion merely that every $\Pi_2$-definable set has an ordinal-definable element. Meanwhile, every model of ZFC has a forcing extension satisfying $V\neq\HOD$ in which every $\Sigma_2$-definable set has an ordinal-definable element. Similar results hold for $\HOD(\mathbb{R})$ and $\HOD(\text{Ord}^\omega)$ and other natural instances of $\HOD(X)$.*
>
> Read more [at the blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/when-does-every-definable-nonempty-set-have-a-definable-element/).

Click on the history to see the original answer. Related questions and answers appear at:

- [Can $V\neq\HOD$, if every $\Sigma_2$-definable set has an ordinal-definable element?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/180850/1946)
- [Is it consistent with ZFC (or ZF) that every definable family of sets has at least one definable member?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/180734/1946)
- We also make use of the $\Sigma_2$ conception of [Local properties in set theory](https://jdh.hamkins.org/local-properties-in-set-theory).

Comment: I need a class A such that ZF proves "A is non empty" and for every class b, ZF doesn't prove "b is in A". Does the difference V \ OD qualify as such a class A? Similarly can ZF prove that the set of Cohen reals over L is nonempty - I'd confess that I've never seen forcing extensions over a class? Probably I'm missing something but it would be great if you can explicitly write the class A. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, V-OD might be empty, and it is in the pointwise definable models. But there is a way to get around this difficulty, and I'll edit my answer above to explain it. Similarly, it is consistent that there are no L-generic Cohen reals.

Comment: That's a nice trick. Reminds me of the proof of relative consistency of "there is no inaccessible". Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you emphasized ZF, as opposed to ZFC, and I went along with this in my answer, but I think the issue of AC does not much affect things here, since the methods for constructing pointwise definable models produce full ZFC models. Although naively one might expect AC to give you non-definable sets, this turns out not to be true, as there are pointwise definable models of full ZFC.

Comment:  For ZFC, I know a particularly nice formula for which this fails: A = set of all well orderings of reals. A is non empty but ZFC doesn't prove that A has a definable member. This example, however, depends on axiom of choice.

Comment: Ah, that is also nice. My OD example seems to work the same in ZF as in ZFC.

Comment: I noticed that your argument for ZF + property (A) -> AC gives a nice characterization of the theories that satisfy property (A): If T is any consistent extension of ZF then, T has property (A) iff T proves V = HOD.

Comment: I see! So the property IS first-order expressible (contrary to what I had said in my first bullet point), and is just equivalent to V=HOD. That is, if a model satisfies V=HOD, then there is a definable well-ordering of the universe, so every nonempty definable set will have a definable element (the least one), and conversely, if the model does not have V=HOD, then the set of minimal rank sets not in OD is definable, but has no definable element.

Comment: Minor edit suggestion: I think the bold phrase in the second paragraph is slightly misleading. The fact that ZF does not imply V=HOD is a definite answer to the question as stated. However, the statement is technically true: if M models ZF and not Con(ZF), then "ZF implies V=HOD" is true in M.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Surely V=HOD is independent of ZF, if anything is. But I see, you are looking at whether "ZF proves V=HOD" is independent? It seems more natural, however, to omit this double provability aspect from the question. The main issue seems to be whether it is true that every definable set has a definable member, and we've now observed that this is just equivalent to V=HOD. I'm half inclined to re-write the answer completely with this perspective, but I don't know what the recommended MO policy on that is.

Comment: It's a minor technical issue which has to do with how the "most direct interpretation of the question" actually reads. Summarized, the question is: does ZF have property (A)? As we now know, this is the same as asking: does ZF imply V=HOD? The answer to that question is no, *because* V=HOD is independent of ZF.

I agree that the answer should be rewritten for clarity. Perhaps writing the new answer above the current one, followed by the historical progression?

Comment: I guess the "it" in the assertion "it is independent of ZF" refers to the meta-scheme: Every definable nonempty class has a definable member. So that, e.g.,  "it" holds in (ZF + V=HOD) while "not-it" holds in (ZF + V!=HOD).

Answer (score 24):

There is a nice model-theoretic interpretation of the property you state, which I will call property (A).

By a *theory of sets*, I mean any theory $T$ with an extensional relation ${\in}$.

Fact 1. If $T$ is a theory of sets with property (A) then so does every extension of $T$.

Fact 2. If $T$ is a complete theory of sets with property (A) then $T$ has a unique prime model.

Fact 3. If $T$ is a complete theory of sets with a wellfounded prime model then $T$ has property (A).

The fact that ZF does not have property (A) follows from Fact 1 and the (simpler) observation that ZFC does not have property (A). However, Facts 2 and 3 give nice ways of finding extensions of ZF which do have property (A).

Without loss of generality, $T$ has enough closed terms so that if $T$ proves that the formula $\phi(x)$ has a unique solution then $T \vdash \phi(c)$ for some closed term $c$. (Otherwise, add a new constant $c$ for each such formula $\phi(x)$ together with the defining axiom $\phi(c)$. This is a conservative extension of $T$ with the desired property.) If $M$ is any model of $T$, then let $K_M$ be the substructure of $M$ whose ground set consists of all interpretations of the closed terms. Note that $K_M$ is completely determined by the complete theory of $M$.

Observe that if $\theta(z)$ is any formula, then 
$\psi(x) \equiv \forall z(z \in x \leftrightarrow \theta(z))$ 
has at most one solution by extensionality. Therefore, $T$ proves that 
$\phi(x) \equiv \psi(x) \lor (\forall z\lnot\psi(z) \land x = c_0)$
has exactly one solution (where $c_0$ is any fixed closed term). So there is a constant $c$ such that, in any model of $T$, if $\{z : \theta(z)\}$ is a set then $c = \{z:\theta(z)\}$. Of course, we always have $c = \{z:z\in c\}$. So in any model $M$ of $T$ the constants $c$ are precisely all the (parameter-free) instances of comprehension which exist in $M$.

In view of this, property (A) can be formulated as:

(A) For every formula $\phi(x)$, if $T \vdash \exists x\phi(x)$ then $T \vdash \phi(c)$ for some constant $c$.

Replacing $\phi(x)$ with $\phi(x) \lor \forall z\lnot\phi(z)$, we see that property (A) implies the seemingly stronger statement:

(A') For every formula $\phi(x)$ there is a constant $c$ such that $T \vdash \exists x \phi(x) \leftrightarrow \phi(c)$.

This reformulation of property (A) immediately implies Fact 1. By the Tarski-Vaught Test, property (A') says that if $M$ is any model of $T$ then the substructure $K_M$ of $M$ is an elementary submodel of $M$. Therefore, $K_M$ is the necessarily unique prime model of the complete theory of $M$, which establishes Fact 2.

For Fact 3, suppose that $T$ is complete and that $M$ is a wellfounded prime model of $T$. I will show that $M = K_M$, which immediately implies that $T$ has property (A). For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $M \neq K_M$. Since $M$ is wellfounded, there is an $a \in M \setminus K_M$ such that $a \subseteq K_M$. Since $M$ is prime, $a$ realizes a principal type $\phi(x)$. If $b$ also realizes $\phi(x)$, then $b \cap K_M = a$ since all elements of $K_M$ are definable. Therefore, $\phi(x)$ must imply $\forall z(\phi(z) \rightarrow x \subseteq z)$ over $T$. This means that $T$ proves that $\phi(x)$ has a unique solution, which contradicts the fact that $a \notin K_M$.

---

To partly answer Joel's comment whether wellfoundedness can be eliminated from Fact 3, Ali Enayat [*Models of set theory with definable ordinals*
Arch. Math. Logic 44 (2005), 363-385. [MR2140616](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2140616)] has shown that for a completion $T$ of $ZF$ the following three properties are equivalent:

1. $T \vdash V = OD$.
2. $T$ has a unique Paris model up to isomorphism.
3. $T$ has a prime model.

A Paris model is a model where every ordinal is first-order definable. This is slightly weaker than property (A), but it is equivalent when $T \vdash V = OD$.

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that property (A) implies the Axiom of Choice---see the edit to my answer. A question: Do you need the prime model to be well-founded in (3)? 

Comment: I suspect that Fact 3 is false assuming only extensionality and not wellfoundedness. I don't know what happens when one assumes much more than just extensionality, like ZF.