# A question about ordinal definable sets of real numbers revisited

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Citing (almost)
[A question about ordinal definable real numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17608/a-question-about-ordinal-definable-real-numbers?rq=1)

If ZFC (Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with the Axiom of Choice) is consistent, does it remain consistent when the following statement is added to it: "There exists a denumerably infinite and ordinal definable set **of real numbers**, not all of whose elements are ordinal definable"

1) If we drop **of real numbers** then, as mentioned elsewhere, a positive answer readily comes in the form of $S=\{X,Y\}$ in the Sacks$\times$Sacks extension $L[x,y]$ of $L$, where $X$ is the $L$-degree of the real $x$ and $Y$ is the $L$-degree of the real $y$, so $X,Y$ are **sets of reals**.

2) As Ali Enayat explained elsewhere, a symmetric extension of $L$ on the base of a Jensen 1970 forcing yields a positive answer with the key absence of AC: it gives a model of ZF.

In the reference above, some approaches (eg, based with the Mathias forcing) were outlined. Has there been any further development possibly with a full answer of the original question?

Comment: First of all, Vladimir, welcome to MathOverflow!  But could you clarify how this question is different than the question to which you link? As far as MO is concerned, no answer has ever been posted. I have heard from Jindrich Zapletal, however, that he claimed to have an answer, and so I recommend contacting him.

Comment: Hello Joel. Yes it is just the same Q, and I wonder has anyone succeeded to solve it, finally. I'll contact Jindra.

Comment: Please do, and then post an answer about it on the other question. This question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Oops, I tried to just vote to close as duplicate, but somehow things have gone wrong. The message that the question is answered on the other question is of course not really accurate, since that answer doesn't yet actually answer the question.

Comment: I have flagged this for moderator attention. Sorry!

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: It's a privilege of the [gold lo.logic badge](http://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/80/lo-logic?userid=1946) to be able to mark [tag:lo.logic] questions as duplicates. This is a system generated message, I think it would have to be changed network-wide.

Comment: I see; it seems that I have unanticipated powers! The question is definitely not answered, although there is of course useful information in Andres's post over there. I think this message probably should be changed network-wide, since I expect that there would be a similar issue arising whenever the original question has answers posted but none accepted.

Comment: The auto-message above even instructs us to "ask a new question", which to my understanding is not the recommended procedure.

Comment: The wording of the message is such because one is indeed not supposed to mark something as a duplicate of a question without answers, and the system will normally not even allow it (IIRC). So the problem is not the message, the problem is the policy (whose rationale I never really understood).

Comment: @Joel: Here is the announcement for your [new gold superpowers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers/254590#254590). The announcement for the new duplicate banner can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595) (2013-02-06).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Is that really the policy? It makes no sense to me. With that policy, if someone were to ask exactly the same question several times in succession, before getting any answers, we wouldn't be able to close the later ones as duplicates.

Comment: But even if that is the policy, there is still a problem with the message, which is that the message says that the original question has been answered, but this is not true. The question has merely had an answer posted, but the question remains unanswered. The further message that "if those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question" is even more problematic and should definitely be changed.

Comment: @Joel: I was looking for more info about this but didn't find what I was looking for. It's apparent that the usage of duplicate on MO and the network has diverged and the community should be aware.

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates .

Comment: Here are the posts I was looking for: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question

Comment: I posted on meta regarding this: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1811/closing-as-duplicate