# Is there a name for sets for which it is easier to test membership than to find members---and vice versa?

Tags: computational-complexity, set-theory, lo.logic, gm.general-mathematics

This is a question my son Bob asked me. For some sets it is relatively easy
to test for membership but a lot more difficult to find members, and for others 
the reverse is true. Here is an elementary example to get the idea across. An
$m \times n$ real matrix $M$ defines a linear map $x \mapsto M x = y$, from
${\mathbb R}^n $ to ${\mathbb R}^m $. It is easy to test if $x$ is in the kernel;
just compute $M x$ and see if it is zero, but to find an $x$ in the kernel you 
must solve $M x = 0$ which is more computationally intensive. Conversely it is 
easy to find an element in the range; just choose any $x$ and compute $M x$; 
but to test if $y$ is in the range you must solve $M x = y$. Does anyone know
if there is a standard name for this distinction or for sets of these two types?

Comment: In $Mx=0$, assuming $x\ne 0$, there are two separate questions: is there such an $x$, and how do you find one if there is one. Conceivably the former could be easy while the latter is hard, so maybe some clarification of the question?

Comment: I don't know of any name for this, but just in case, to clarify: Would the set of transcendental numbers be another example? Are you specifically interested in subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? And are you only measuring difficulty in terms of computational complexity, as opposed to something else? (What could I mean by "something else"? There are results in descriptive set theory stating that definable sets of certain complexity must contain definable members of certain complexity.) 

Comment: Bjørn: Remember, this is only meant as an example, so think of $M$ as a generic matrix, in which case I believe the two questions really are the same.

Comment: It's only meant as an example, so I'll take a different example... if we let $f(x)$ be the unary representation of $x$, where $x$ is a number given in binary, then $f(x)$ always exists (so the question whether it exists is trivial), but is time-intensive to compute. 

Comment: Andres: I had not thought of it, but yes, the set of transcendentals is another very nice example. The Liouville construction gives a very easy method for constructing them, but it is very difficult to test if a particular number is transcendental. And, I was thinking mainly in terms of computational complexity, but I would certainly be interested in other meanings. What is a good reference for the descriptive set theory result you mentioned?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function

Comment: I would expect that Kechris's "Classical descriptive set theory" contains examples of these `basis results' that do not require too much background from logic. If logic is not an issue, Alain Louveau has a draft of a very comprehensive book on effective descriptive set theory that covers some of them. Moschovakis's book on Descriptive set theory should have other examples as well, not too far from Borel sets. The example I was thinking of, actually, was from the paper Donald A. Martin-Robert M. Solovay. "A basis theorem for $\sum_{3}^{1}$ sets of reals", Ann. of Math. (2) 89 1969 138--159. 

Comment: Steve: Certainly the concept of a one-way function is highly relevant. If a set has a characteristic function that is one-way, then that means it is easy to check for membership, but difficult to find an element. 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This phenomenon occurs both positively and negatively in
many parts of logic, but to my knowledge, there is no
particular adjective that is always used in such
situations.

- In classical *computability theory*, the first phenomenon does not
  occur. If one can computably test membership in a set, in
  the usual Turing sense, then one can computably generate
  an instance, simply because one can computably enumerate
  all objects in the domain of discourse, and systematically
  test them. This is related to the classical fact that if the graph of a
  function is decidable, then the function is computable.

Thus, to my mind, the phenomenon is intimately
wrapped up with the ability to effectively enumerate, in the relevant sense, the
objects in the domain of discourse.

- The converse situation, however, does occur in computability theory, and is a central phenomenon. Namely, there are sets of natural numbers whose members can be systematically generated---so the set is computably enumerable---but whose membership test is not computable. These are exactly the sets that are c.e. but not computable. Examples would include the halting problem (the set of programs $e$ halting on trivial input) and many other examples. It is easy to generate many halting programs---one can systematically enumerate them---but impossible to test in general if a given program halts. There is an intensively-studied hierarchy of Turing degrees instantiated by c.e. sets that are not decidable.
- In *complexity theory*, there is a sense in which there are
  negative examples. One can imagine a polynomial-time
  decidable set $A$, all of whose members are very large,
  and hence difficult to produce. To make the problem
  precise, however, one should really have a sequence $A_n$
  of sets such that membership $x\in A_n$ is polynomial
  time decidable in $(x,n)$---that is, uniformly in
  $n$---but such that there is no polynomial time
  computable function $f$ such that $f(n)\in A_n$. Such an
  example is provided simply by the sets $A_n$ consisting
  of all numbers at least $2^n$. Given a pair $(x,n)$, it
  is polynomial-time decidable in $(x,n)$ whether $x\geq
    2^n$, but there is no polynomial function exceeding
  $n\mapsto 2^n$.

Similar examples would be provided by any sequence of sets
$A_n$, all of whose members were very large in comparison
with $n$, but such that the membership problem $x\in A_n$
is easily decided.

- In various sorts of higher computability theory, there
  are additional negative instances. For example, with the
  theory of infinite time Turing machines, there are
  infinite time decidable sets of reals with no computable members.
  Indeed, the Lost Melody Theorem asserts precisely that there are infinite
  time decidable singletons $\{c\}$, such that the real
  $c$ is not writable by any infinite time Turing machine.
  That is, there are reals $c$, such that it is decidable
  by infinite time Turing machines whether a given real $x$
  is $c$ or not, by no such machine can produce $c$ on its
  own. This seems to be the essence of your phenomenon. (The
  ``lost melody'' terminology arises from the situation,
  where a person is able to recognize a given melody when someone else
  sings it, but is unable to sing it on their own.)
- In descriptive set theory, one would look at whether a
  set of reals at a given level in the descriptive
  set-theoretic hierarchy has members at that same level.
  This is false in general, although there are special circumstances
  (some involving large cardinal hypotheses) in which instances
  of it are true. One way to look at it
  is as a Choice principle: given a subset $A$ of the plane
  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, can one find a function $f$
  of the same complexity with $\text{dom}(f)=\text{dom}(A)$ such that
  $(x,f(x))\in A$ for all $x\in\text{dom}(A)$? This problem is also
  known as the *uniformization* problem.
- In a more general set theoretic setting, it is natural to consider
  the situation of ordinal-definable sets. Does every
  non-empty ordinal definable set contain an
  ordinal-definable member? This turns out to be equivalent
  to the assertion known as $V=HOD$, which is independent of
  ZFC, as explained in the edited version of [this MO
  answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10413/definable-collections-without-definable-members-in-zf/10415#10415).
  The reason is that the set of non-ordinal-definable sets of
  minimal rank is ordinal definable.

Comment: This happens in other areas of computability theory as well. In Blum/Shub/Smale computability, it is possible for a set to be semidecidable even though it is not enumerable; I have heard the set of algebraic numbers give an example of this. In alpha recursion theory, the very definition of "enumerable" is made in terms of semidecidability rather than in terms of what is usually thought of as enumerability. Classical computability theory on the natural numbers is somewhat unique in making enumerability and semidecidability equivalent. 

Comment: The consensus seems to be that there is no standard name for this phenomenon, but I have learned a lot from the answers about the many and varied situations in which it comes up. My thanks to all---and particularly to Joel for his well thought out and informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

[A similar question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1848/easy-decision-problem-hard-search-problem) was asked at cstheory.stackexchange; there are several examples from computational complexity given there.  However, I agree that there seems to be no standard name for such things.